# Using isin to simulate sql's IN clause

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(10,'z')]),['id','value'])
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([(1,'x'),(2,'y')]),['id','value'])

>>> df1.show()
```

```
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|    b|
|  3|    c|
| 10|    z|
+---+-----+
```

I want to simulate  `select df1.* from df1 where df1.id in (select df2.id from df2)`.  How do I do it using `isin`?

I tried some but didn't work which means I am missing something important.

```
df1.where(col('id').isin(df2['id']))

df1.where(col('id').isin(*df2.id)).show() //isin() argument after * must be a sequence, not Column

df1.where(col('id').isin(tuple(df2.id))) //Column is not iterable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a local collection to work with `isin`, while a data frame column is distributed. Alternatively you can use `inner join` to filter the data frame:

```
df1.join(df2.select('id').dropDuplicates(), ['id']).show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|    b|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use the exact query you provided with pyspark-sql:

```python
df1.registerTempTable('df1')
df2.registerTempTable('df2')
query = "select df1.* from df1 where df1.id in (select df2.id from df2)"
sqlContext.sql(query).show()
#+---+-----+
#| id|value|
#+---+-----+
#|  1|    a|
#|  2|    b|
#+---+-----+
```